# Send notification when a custom log message is delivered to GCP Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to create a notification when a custom log message is sent to stackdriver?

For ex, when the below message is logged to stackdriver, immediately a notification needs to be sent to the configured email address.

```
{
    "jsonPayload": {
        "message": "job is successfully completed"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can export Stackdriver to Pub/Sub. Pub/Sub triggers Cloud Run or Cloud Functions which filters on what you are looking for and sends an email. Start here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/design-patterns-for-exporting-stackdriver-logging

Comment: This article shows how to set up Stackdriver alerts which might work for you. https://medium.com/searce/how-to-push-serial-console-output-logs-to-stackdriver-and-set-alerts-in-gcp-1a4d61da7c4c